# Use copy method on Docu class

Tags: class, methods, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

When i create a Sales Order from a Customer i want to copy the document handling records from the customer to the Sales Order.

Therefore i want to use the copy method which exists on the Docu class.

I am not sure how to implement this in the SalesTable, i want to run this method after `insert()` on the `SalesTable`

I have tried to make a start with the following code:

```
if (CustTable::find(this.CustAccount))
{
    Docu::copy(_from, this.SalesId)
}
```

But i am stuck how to accomplish this.

The 2nd step is that i only want to copy documents with a specificed Document direction, but i guess i can figure that out once i know the right way to copy the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy` method expects two records.

After the `super()` in `SalesTable.insert` you can do this:

```
Docu::copy(this.custTable_CustAccount(), this);
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me! Now i am trying to create an if statement to check on the requirement for Document direction, do i need to create a new method on the CustTable to check if the requirements meet and return a true boolean? And then check for the boolean before Docu::copy?

Comment: You definitely need to do the check before the copy, like:  
`if (this.custTable_CustAccount().DocuCopy2Sales)`.   
Whether that takes another method is up to you.